# node js synchronous foreach easy example?

Tags: node.js

I want to handle `nodejs`  asynchronous issue. 
please help  me with a sweet example - it ll be better for me if you able to do it by callback or like callback related thing.

Thanks

Comment: Didn't you find anything on the internet?

Comment: I unable to find out  the the proper one ..can you help me out please? i am new in node js

Comment: Yes we can help you, but it's not quite clear what are you trying to ask. Please elaborate further whether you're talking about `forEach` method in javascript or callbacks in general

Comment: i am using a foreach -> and inside the  foreach doing lots of functions , do i want to do when forech one round execution totaly complete than it ll move to  next round  ...need an eaxple

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446) and see if it helps. It has got some examples of `forEach`

Comment: oppps! i know foreach  i want help on synchronous  foreach ...https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-each take a look i unable to implement it .

Answer (score 0):

Sample examples

Foreach loop

```
var fs = require('fs')
var paths = ['/home' , '/root', '/var']
paths.forEach(function( path ) {
  fs.lstat( path, function(err, stat) {
    console.log( path, stat );
  });
});
```

For loop

```
for (var i = 0, c = paths.length; i < c; i++)
{
  // creating an Immiedately Invoked Function Expression
  (function( path ) {
    fs.lstat(path, function (error, stat) {
      console.log(path, stat);
    });
  })( paths[i] );
  // passing paths[i] in as "path" in the closure
}
```

Recursion

```
    function iteratePath(paths, i, max){
      if(i<max) {
       return;
      }else{
          fs.lstat( path, function(err, stat) {
            console.log( path, stat );
            //Recursive call back
            iteratePath(paths, i, max)
          });
        }
    }

var paths = ['/home' , '/root', '/var']
iteratePath(paths,0, size)
```

You can use async 
[Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: thanks for the example Devaraj , are you sure about ..var fs = require('fs')
var paths = ['/home' , '/root', '/var']
paths.forEach(function( path ) {
  fs.lstat( path, function(err, stat) {
    console.log( path, stat );
  });
});